# Pygments syntax highlighting in Jekyll without starting a <div>

Tags: clojure, jekyll, pygments

If you use Jekyll with the Pygments syntax-highlighting package, it’s possible to write

```
{% highlight clojure %}
(def something :foobar)
{% endhighlight %}
```

which produces a `<div>` containing that line, syntax-highlighted according to Clojure syntax. But is there a way to get the syntax highlighting in the middle of a paragraph? I’d like to be able to write

```
In Clojure, keywords like {% highlight clojure %}:foobar{% endhighlight %}
are prepended by colons.
```

The desired behavior here is that the Clojure keyword would be highlighted using the same style as was used for the keyword in the first example.  When I try to do this, though, it just produces a `<div>` like before. (And maybe this is specific to the Kramdown markdown engine I’m using, but the div tag itself is HTML-escaped so that you can see “<div>” right there in the generated text.)

Is there a way to get Jekyll/Pygments to do “inline” syntax highlighting like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two years later, I went ahead and created my own Jekyll plugin to provide inline syntax highlighting. It’s called [inline_highlight](https://github.com/bdesham/inline_highlight) and it can be used like so:

```
In Clojure, keywords like {% ihighlight clojure %}:foobar{% endihighlight %}
are prepended by colons.
```

Comment: This is nice, but for those of you using Jekyll with github pages it won't work. That is because github pages does not allow custom plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CSS class to any object you put in a post.

If you define a CSS entry like this:

```
.inlined { display:inline; }
```

You can then add this class to the generated `<div>` doing this:

```
In Clojure, keywords like 
{% highlight clojure %}:foobar{% endhighlight %}{: .inlined } 
are prepended by colons.
```

This works with all kind of objects (tables, images, etc). I can not test it right now, but I think this will solve the issue.

When you test it, look at the output HTML. You will then find that your `<div>` now has the `class=inlined` attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the `nowrap` option to prevent Pygments from wrapping the code in a `div` tag. So your example would become:

```
In Clojure, keywords like 
<span class='highlight'><code class='closure'>
{% highlight clojure nowrap %}:foobar{% endhighlight %}
</code></span>
are prepended by colons.
```

Comment: This didn’t work for me… adding `nowrap` doesn’t change the output at all. Where did you hear about this option?

Comment: I think that I found it in the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/7304e4759ae65343d89a51359ca538912519cc31/pygments/formatters/html.py?at=default#cl-186)

Answer (score 0):

My quick workaround was letting Jekyll preprocess the code:

```
<div class="highlight">
    <code class="language-css" data-lang="css">…</code>
</div>
```

And paste it into a desirable place after replacing divs with spans:

```
<span class="highlight">
    <code class="language-css" data-lang="css">…</code>
</span>
```