# How do I get in-line code with Jekyll and Pygments?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, jekyll, css, pygments

I'm using Markdown with Liquid tags to mark up some code for a Jekyll-generated site and would like to include some code that is both in-line (in a paragraph) and has coloured syntax (with Pygments), but it does not appear to work.

The markup

```
Lorem ipsum dolor {% highlight javascript %} var sit = "amet"; {% endhighlight %} consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

results in

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <div class='highlight'><pre><code class='javascript'> <span class='kd'>var</span> <span class='nx'>sit</span> <span class='o'>=</span> <span class='s2'>&quot;amet&quot;</span><span class='p'>;</span></code></pre></div> consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

I would very much like highlighted text not be wrapped in `<div class='highlight'>`, or at least have it be a `<span class='highlight'>`.

Using `{% highlight javascript nowrap %}` does not work, as [suggested elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12441501/pygments-syntax-highlighting-in-jekyll-without-starting-a-div). (Perhaps this is an issue with my setup—which is Ruby 2.0, Jekyll 0.12.1, pygments.rb 0.3.7?)

I would like to [host this page on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages), which means *I cannot rely on a plugin*. Bummer, right?

**Addendum:** Line numbering (ie. `{% highlight javascript linenos %}`) does not appear to work either. Man.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do this is to use Github Flavoured Markdown and use their default inline code.

in your `_config.yml` file, change your markdown to redcarpet. You're now ready to go with GFM.

```
markdown: redcarpet
```

Now you can follow all the [GitHub Markdown](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet). To do inline code as follow:

```
Here is some `inline code` in the middle of sencence
```

Comment: Normal inline code is easy. The issue is getting Pygments *syntax highlighted* inline code.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a CSS class to any object you put in a post.

If you define a CSS entry like this:

```
.inlined { display:inline; }
```

You can then add this class to the generated `<div>` doing this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor 
{% highlight javascript %}var sit="amet"; {% endhighlight %}{: .inlined } 
consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

This works with all kind of objects (tables, images, etc). I can not test it right now, but I think this will solve the issue.

When you test it, look at the output HTML. You will then find that your `<div>` now has the `class=inlined` attribute set.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain why so I can improve or correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with the .highlight div? It's put there to make syntax highlighting easy to theme. 
To change the wrapper to a span my bet is that you haveto change Jekyll configuration.

Linenumbers only appear when you have a multi-line snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the following two functions (and call them):

```js
var inlineElements = function() {
    var inlinedElements = document.getElementsByClassName('inlined');
    inlinedElements = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], inlinedElements); // copy
    for (var i = 0; i < inlinedElements.length; i++) {
        var div = inlinedElements[i];
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = div.children[0].innerHTML;
        var previous = div.previousElementSibling;
        var paragraph;
        if (previous.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'p') {
            paragraph = previous;
        } else {
            paragraph = document.createElement('p');
            div.parentNode.insertBefore(paragraph, div);
        }
        div.remove();
        paragraph.innerHTML += ' ' + span.innerHTML + ' ';
        paragraph.classList.add('highlight');
        paragraph.classList.add('inlined');
        if (div.classList.contains('connectNext')) {
            paragraph.classList.add('connectNext');
        }
    }
}

var connectElements = function() {
    while (true) {
        var connectNextElements = document.getElementsByClassName('connectNext');
        if (connectNextElements.length == 0) break;
        var prefix = connectNextElements[0];
        var next = prefix.nextElementSibling;
        prefix.innerHTML += ' ' + next.innerHTML;
        next.remove();
        if (!next.classList.contains('connectNext')) {
            prefix.classList.remove('connectNext');
        }
    }
}

inlineElements();
connectElements();
```

You can use .inline and .connectNext in your Markdown:

```jekyll
{% highlight objective-c %}
[[NSObject alloc] init];
{% endhighlight %} {: .inlined .connectNext }
vs.
{% highlight java %}
new Object();
{% endhighlight %} {: .inlined }
```

`.connectNext` will make ensure that the text following the code block is also inlined in the same `<p>`.